# Как уменьшить нагрузку сервера mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, npm

У меня в качестве базы данных есть `mongodb`.
В некой таблице например `messages` есть 10.000 записей (документов таблицы).
Я включил `setInterval` 1 сек, и через каждую секунду у меня идет запрос к базе чтобы вывести 200 сообщений (размер каждого сообщения 2.5 кб) из 10.000, и это операция у меня занимает 1.5 сек, Но если я вместо 1 сек поставлю `setInterval` 10 мс, то время операции будет потихоньку возрастать, почему я вместо 1 сек поставил 10 мс? Это типо тестинг нагрузки. Собственно вопрос: что делать?

Comment: Запросы к БД - дорогая операция, попробуйте поиграться с кешированием запросов (`redis`). Так же имеет смысл изменить запросы к базе, перейдя от множества частых и мелких к нескольким редким и большим.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую